# Making a mobile battery charger for smart phones

Tags: batteries, charger, mobile

i want to make a mobile charger and charge multiple mobiles at a time 
therefore i select a 5V 2A adapter and a USB hub with 4 ports check the image

what i am going to do with this adapter and USB hub is, i will remove the USB HUB circuit so that electricity goes directly to USB port and just use the USB ports for chargers by making a series connection directly from adapters to USB ports so that each port supply 5V constant and 2A if incase only 1 mobile is connected

Now my question is what i am going to do is correct ?

Is there any other safe way to do this ?

what is the safest way to make a charger ?

Should i remove the USB HUB circuit or no need ?

Just with this 2 items i can charge multiple mobiles at a time and charge it with 2ampere ?

[image]

Comment: I really wouldn't bother. Just use it as is.

Comment: i have one of those super-cheap hubs, and it doesn't pass more than 700ma total. i suspect the male connector though; solder onto the common rails and it should improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB spec only allows for 500mA output current per port.

Before a phone tries to take more than 500mA is should communicate over the data lines and find out what the maximum supported current it. With your plan this communication will fail and the phone should limit its charging rate to the USB specification limits.

Comment: keyword: _should_. having messed with dozens of phones, i've never seen one that only charges at 500ma on a dumb charger...